# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference

Tags: java, itext

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference

I am getting this error in the program that I wrote to convert a PDF file to XML file. How can it be caused and how can I solve it?

```
`package pkgfinal.year;

 import java.io.*;
 import org.xml.sax.*;
 import javax.xml.parsers.*;
 import javax.xml.transform.*;
 import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
 import javax.xml.transform.sax.*;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
 import com.itextpdf.text.*;
 import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;
 import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser;



 public class FinalYear {
    static StreamResult streamResult;
    static TransformerHandler handler;
    static AttributesImpl atts;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            try {
                    Document document = new Document();
                    document.open();
                   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("TestFiles/test.pdf"); 
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fis);
                    PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
                    PRIndirectReference objectReference = (PRIndirectReference)         page.get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
                    PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader
                                    .getPdfObject(objectReference);
                    byte[] streamBytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
                    PRTokeniser tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(streamBytes);

                    StringBuilder strbufe = new StringBuilder();
                    while (tokenizer.nextToken()) {
                            if (tokenizer.getTokenType() == PRTokeniser.TK_STRING) {
                                    strbufe.append(tokenizer.getStringValue());
                            }
                    }
                    String test = strbufe.toString();
                    streamResult = new StreamResult("TestFiles/output1.xml");
                    initXML();
                    process(test);
                    closeXML();
                    document.add(new Paragraph(".."));
                    document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
    }

    public static void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException,
                    TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
            SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory
                            .newInstance();

            handler = tf.newTransformerHandler();
            Transformer serializer = handler.getTransformer();
            serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
            serializer.setOutputProperty(
                            "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            handler.setResult(streamResult);
            handler.startDocument();
            atts = new AttributesImpl();
            handler.startElement("", "", "Title", atts);
    }

    public static void process(String s) throws SAXException {
            String[] elements = s.split("\\|");
            atts.clear();
            handler.startElement("", "", "Message", atts);
            handler.characters(elements[0].toCharArray(), 0, elements[0].length());
            handler.endElement("", "", "Message");
    }

    public static void closeXML() throws SAXException {
            handler.endElement("", "", "Title");
            handler.endDocument();
    }
 }
```

the above is the code that is throwing the error. The line which shows the error is double starred or is in bold. Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a class of PdfArray to a class of PRIndirectReference.

If you provided the code that is doing this more assistance would be forth coming but looking at the error message as it stands you are trying to cast one class to another that is not able to be instantiated from it.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from the code is that you trying to assign the return value of  `page.get(PdfName.CONTENTS);` to `PRIndirectReference` which is throwing a ClassCastException. This infers that `page.get(..)` is not returing an object of `PRIndirectReference` type or any of its subclasses type.

You probably need to add a suitable kind of wrapper here which return the proper kind of class or subclass that can be cast to `PRIndirectReference`. Browsing through the 'itextpdf' documentaion, I think you were about to use `PDFIndirectReference` class and ended up using a wrong one.